# Why must Maven always download a hell of things

Tags: java, maven

One starts using maven following the guide at [Maven getting started](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_Maven), creates his first my-app project which consists of an empty directory and issues the command to create a maven project:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
  -DartifactId=my-app
```

now the following hell of things is downloaded for him:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (759 B at 0.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.4/maven-archetype-plugin-2.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.4/maven-archetype-plugin-2.4.pom (9 KB at 52.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/maven-archetype/2.4/maven-archetype-2.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/maven-archetype/2.4/maven-archetype-2.4.pom (13 KB at 62.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.4/maven-archetype-plugin-2.4.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/2.4/maven-archetype-plugin-2.4.jar (92 KB at 74.5 KB/sec)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/2.4/archetype-catalog-2.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/2.4/archetype-catalog-2.4.pom (2 KB at 11.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-models/2.4/archetype-models-2.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-models/2.4/archetype-models-2.4.pom (3 KB at 12.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-descriptor/2.4/archetype-descriptor-2.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-descriptor/2.4/archetype-descriptor-2.4.pom (2 KB at 7.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-registry/2.4/archetype-registry-2.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-registry/2.4/archetype-registry-2.4.pom (2 KB at 7.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-common/2.4/archetype-common-2.4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-common/2.4/archetype-common-2.4.pom (16 KB at 42.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/jchardet/jchardet/1.0/jchardet-1.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/jchardet/jchardet/1.0/jchardet-1.0.pom (2 KB at 7.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.pom (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.pom (2 KB at 10.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.pom (3 KB at 11.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-containers-1.0-alpha-16.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-containers-1.0-alpha-16.pom (2 KB at 9.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.pom (32 KB at 65.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.pom (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.2/asm-3.2.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.2/asm-3.2.pom (264 B at 1.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-parent/3.2/asm-parent-3.2.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-parent/3.2/asm-parent-3.2.pom (5 KB at 18.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-commons/3.2/asm-commons-3.2.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-commons/3.2/asm-commons-3.2.pom (415 B at 2.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-tree/3.2/asm-tree-3.2.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-tree/3.2/asm-tree-3.2.pom (404 B at 2.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.pom (409 B at 2.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.pom (417 B at 2.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.pom (2 KB at 5.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/beanshell/2.0b4/beanshell-2.0b4.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/beanshell/2.0b4/beanshell-2.0b4.pom (2 KB at 5.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-script-interpreter/1.0/maven-script-interpreter-1.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-script-interpreter/1.0/maven-script-interpreter-1.0.pom (4 KB at 14.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.pom (9 KB at 16.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.1/ant-parent-1.8.1.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-parent/1.8.1/ant-parent-1.8.1.pom (5 KB at 23.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-descriptor/2.4/archetype-descriptor-2.4.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/2.4/archetype-catalog-2.4.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-common/2.4/archetype-common-2.4.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-registry/2.4/archetype-registry-2.4.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/jchardet/jchardet/1.0/jchardet-1.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-catalog/2.4/archetype-catalog-2.4.jar (19 KB at 88.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.8/plexus-velocity-1.1.8.jar (8 KB at 13.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-6/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-registry/2.4/archetype-registry-2.4.jar (17 KB at 28.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-6/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar (12 KB at 14.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2-alpha-7/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-7.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.jar (33 KB at 35.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sourceforge/jchardet/jchardet/1.0/jchardet-1.0.jar (26 KB at 26.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-descriptor/2.4/archetype-descriptor-2.4.jar (23 KB at 21.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.2/asm-3.2.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-commons/3.2/asm-commons-3.2.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-commons/3.2/asm-commons-3.2.jar (33 KB at 23.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetype/archetype-common/2.4/archetype-common-2.4.jar (170 KB at 117.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.2/asm-3.2.jar (43 KB at 27.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-tree/3.2/asm-tree-3.2.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-util/3.2/asm-util-3.2.jar (36 KB at 22.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-analysis/3.2/asm-analysis-3.2.jar (18 KB at 10.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-script-interpreter/1.0/maven-script-interpreter-1.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2-alpha-7/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-7.jar (42 KB at 24.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-script-interpreter/1.0/maven-script-interpreter-1.0.jar (21 KB at 10.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-tree/3.2/asm-tree-3.2.jar (22 KB at 11.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar (276 KB at 90.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.jar (1479 KB at 124.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar (5394 KB at 220.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] No archetype defined. Using maven-archetype-quickstart (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0.jar (5 KB at 13.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/1.0/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0.pom (703 B at 2.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /home/frgs/mvntest+
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: com.mycompany.app
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: com.mycompany.app
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: my-app
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: com.mycompany.app
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: /home/frgs/mvntest+/my-app
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 56.119 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-14T18:00:05+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/166M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does that look normal? again I'm talking of a project consisting of an empty directory, this looke ridiculous to me if it weren't for the fact that practically every Java project on github uses maven!

Comment: It should only have to download all those things once.

Comment: That's the magic of Maven. Embrace it. No really embrace it. Better than having to go look for everything yourself and downloading them. In your case on a new project with no dependencies it is just downloading the plugins. Maven works off plugins so the more new plugins you use, it will need to download them. As chrylis said, only one (per version). When you start adding dependencies, it will download those too. Then they are put into your local repo. So if you ever use them again, they will be available locally

Comment: Keep in mind that maven also downloads the necessary plugins for it to perform the necessary actions.

Comment: Create another project the same way, and you will see the same artifacts will not be downloaded

Comment: Look at ~/.m2. Tada!

Comment: @TassosBassoukos is correct.  The majority of what got downloaded here are components maven needs to do the things it does.

Comment: Unfortunately happens very often than one dependency over a 100 is not available and maven breaks. My project so far includes directly the libraries as jars inside lib/ folder, no way the project can break once you checked out the project with git. Maybe I will change my mind but on this topic maven doesn't shine in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

That's how the maven works. 
All the dependencies which can be 3rdparty jars, plugins dependencies of plugins and in general any jar that may be required for running the project should be accessible locally.
So maven manages them all by connecting to one or more "remote locations" (repositories). These are just like a big file system that contains various jars and metadata.

In maven you get a dependency management "for free".
This means that it can manage all your dependencies by itself. This includes downloading to some predefined folder (known as local repo) from those remote locations and "arranging" the classpath for your project.
If the dependency has its own dependencies they will be downloaded as well. This concept is known as "transitive dependency".

Now, in order to "fill" the local repo maven has to download the jars to your local hard drive, that's why you see that it downloads a lot of stuff.

So, answering your question, yes its normal maven behavior. In addition maven is intelligent enough to download the dependency only once, for the second time you use it, it should examine the local repository and if it finds the dependency it won't download it again.

Maybe one point I can add here:
There is a way to tell to maven "run in an offline mode". This means that it won't have an access to the network.
in order to do that just specify '-o option'. Example:

```
mvn install -o
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if you specify offline mode how do you indicate where to fetch the files? that would complete your answer.